# Create action for invites

Tags: ios, swift

In my iOS application, I want to put a feature which will send invites to people selected in other applications like WhatsApp or other messaging services. I have no idea how to go about it. Please help me in this regard. A little guidance will be appreciated.

I tried to use WhatsApp to send invites. But I was unable to achieve it.

```
@IBAction func invite(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let ReferCode = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "ReferCode") ?? ""
        let originalString = ReferCode
        let escapedString = originalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)

        let url  = URL(string: "whatsapp://send?text= Your referral code is\(escapedString!)")

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url! as URL)
        {
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        }
    }
```

When I am pressing the invite button, the app is crashing.

Comment: Show the message and stack trace for the crash.  Print the value of `url` before your `if` statement.

Comment: Actually, Simulator doesn't have WhatsApp.

Comment: Does that mean you now understand why it crashed?

Comment: I am getting nil value. Please guide me how to achieve invites for the app using referral code that I have.

Comment: I don't know anything about WhatsApp.  I just know about crashes.  :)  (If you have a variable that might be `nil`, don't use `!` on it.)

Comment: Okay.. Thanks for taking time to review.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `nil` value in `referCode` then it might be crash. use conditional unwrapping for optional values.

```
@IBAction func invite(_ sender: UIButton) {

        guard let referCode = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "ReferCode") else {
            debugPrint("referCode not available")
            return
        }
        let escapedString = referCode.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)

        guard let url  = URL(string: "whatsapp://send?text= Your referral code is \(String(describing: escapedString))") else {
            debugPrint("URL not correct")
            return
        }

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)
        {
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        }
    }
```